# Simple linear regression: confidence interval?

Tags: regression, self-study, standard-error

Given data $(x_{1}, y_{2}),..., (x_{n}, y_{n})$, consider the simple linear regression model $E(Y | X=x) =3.2 + B_{1}x, Var(Y|X=x)=\sigma^{2}$. Construct a 95% confidence interval for $B_{1}$.

I know that we first have to estimate the $\sigma$, but I was told that the degrees of the confidence interval is n-1, which I don't get because doesn't the simple linear regression have 2 degrees of freedom since there are 2 parameters?

Also, I calculated the variance of $\hat{B_{1}}$ to be $\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\Sigma {x_{i}}^{2}}$ but I don't know why in the confidence interval, the $se(\hat{B_{1}}) = \frac{\hat{\sigma}}{\Sigma{x_{i}}^{2}}$.

I would really appreciate it if someone can explain my two issues to me.

Comment: For your 1st question: The $\hat{\beta}_0=3.2$ is given, so you know this parameter. Does that help? If this is a homework, add a self-study tag.

Comment: The intercept $3.2$ is assumed to be known ?

Comment: @Stat: What does that mean? I thought the simple linear regression had two parameters, the intercept and the first term?

Comment: It means that they may be some situations where you know one of the parameters. For example: suppose you want to find the relation between the weight $Y$ of a person and the time $X$ due to a special diet. Then for sure you know that at time zero the weight is for example 65 kg. So when $X=0$, your $Y=65$. This means that in linear model $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X$, your $\beta_0=65$. So you know this parameter before fitting. Also you may expect your estimated $\beta_1$ to be negative!. This may not be a perfect example, but will give you an idea.

Comment: @Stat: Oh, so if one of the parameters are known, it is subtracted from n? So in this case, since the intercept is known, we subtract just 1?